# How to stop stop music playing in android WebView when Incoming Call and Outgoing call?

Tags: android

Kindly please help to show me the way to stop the music playing in WebView when get incoming call and Outgoing Call?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps pausing the thread the WebView is on for the duration of the call? I assume this would stop the sound.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the phone state listener and on an incoming call you can use `Yourwebview.stopLoading()`
method to stop playing music.

Give it a try ...